# How to forwarding / relay WebRTC Video for Peer to Peer Broadcasting in Webrtc

Tags: webrtc

How we can forward/relay the media stream  to another rtc peer connection

Is there any source available for to check this functionality. For example  Peer A  <-- Relay to  ---> Peer B.   <-- --Relay to -> Peer C.
Is Singaling is required to achieve this functionality.